# How to structure a single page meteor app with pixijs?

Tags: meteor, amd, pixi.js

So I'm trying to port this fantastic tutorial -https://goo.gl/rTZA0d - on using pixi.js within meteor, and I'm rather stuck on how I can modularize the code outside of onRendered. Here's the gist - https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4502af95ce67465550fa.

What I want to be able to do is handle events via meteor and pass it into the pixi framework, and of course build the business logic around the framework inside of meteor and/or meteor packages. For example, a package module to handle the loading of assets, etc. I feel like I'm going up a creek without a paddle here, any ideas if this is a valid approach, and/or I'm wasting my time marrying the two. The thought of having a real-time framework using pixijs excites me, yet I'm not familiar with the how part.